# UIBarButtonItem clone

Tags: iphone, button, gradient

I have an UIButton subclass and I need its look
to be identical to an UIBarButtonItem when placed on the
classic blue tinted navigation bar.

[image: UIBarButtonItem]

The UIBarButtonItem has a border with a kind-of gradient,
being darker at the top and blue-ish at the bottom, which
I suspect it's done with some alpha trick. The bottom
looks recessed too.

There's also some overlay which makes the button a little bit darker
and even more when in the selected state.

Can anyone help?

Comment: since iOS 5 the UIBarButtonItem has more customizaion options and a new MKUserTrackingBarButtonItem has been introduced, which is what I wanted to craft.

Answer (score 1):

The short answer is that you are going to have to spend some time learning how to draw gradients and shadows in Core Graphics.

The relevant documentation is called "Quartz 2D Programming Guide".

After you learn how to draw shadows and gradients, you are going to have to spend quite a bit of time zoomed in comparing what you are drawing vs what the button looks like.

You didn't ask, but this is what I would do:

Subclass UIBarButtonItem and add your custom functionality in there.  Let UIBarButtonItem draw itself.

Comment: seems doable, I'll try overriding drawRect and adding subviews of my own. ty.

Comment: UIBarButtonItem is not the class that gets drawn, but only a "descriptor" of the button itself. The navigation bar does some magic and allocates an instance of a private class to do the actual drawing.

Answer (score 0):

It might be easier for you just to use a photoshopped image. Use the image for your button. This way you don't have to worry about custom drawing code.

Comment: A photoshopped image won't work with different navigation bar colors. I'd like a pure-code solution.

Comment: Then use multiple photoshop images.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Three20 library,
specially have a look at sample TTCatalog app.

Look at the source file "StyleTestController.m"

https://github.com/facebook/three20/blob/master/samples/TTCatalog/Classes/StyleTestController.m

I'm sure you'll find your answer here.

Cheers,